# Split - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, split

Im using the following code to split up a string and store it:

```
string[] proxyAdrs = linesProxy[i].Split(':');
string proxyServer = proxyAdrs[0];
int proxyPort = Convert.ToInt32(proxyAdrs[1]);


if(proxyAdrs[2] != null)
{
    item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
}

if (proxyAdrs[3] != null)
{
    item.Password = proxyAdrs[3];
}
```

The problem is i am getting

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

When `proxyAdrs[2]` is not there.

Sometimes proxyAdrs[2] will be there sometimes not.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just check the length of the array returned in your if statement

```
if( proxyAdrs.Length > 2 &&  proxyAdrs[2] != null)
    {
        item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
    }
```

The reason you are getting the exception is that the split is returning array of size less than the index you are accessing with. If you are accessing the array element `2` then there must be atleast `3` elements in the array as array index starts with `0`

Answer (score 3):

You can check the length of array before accessing its element by index.

Change

```
   if(proxyAdrs[2] != null)
   {
            item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
   }
```

To

```
   if(proxyAdrs.Length > 2 )
   {
            item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string[] proxyAdrs = linesProxy[i].Split(':');
        string proxyServer = proxyAdrs[0];
        int proxyPort = Convert.ToInt32(proxyAdrs[1]);


        if(proxyAdrs.Length > 2 && proxyAdrs[2] != null)
        {
            item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
        }

        if (proxyAdrs.Length > 3 && proxyAdrs[3] != null)
        {
            item.Password = proxyAdrs[3];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of `proxyAdrs` before you attempt to subscript a potentially non-existent item.

```
if ( proxyAdrs.Length > 1 ) {
  item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is that your `i` which might be lower than the `2` you are trying to set in as index :)

`if i >= 2` then you can do all of the follwing:----

```
if(proxyAdrs[2] != null)
        {
            item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
        }

        if (proxyAdrs[3] != null)
        {
            item.Password = proxyAdrs[3];
        }
}
else I suggest you get out :D
```

But again, checking `proxyAdrs.Lenght` would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that may help you, depending of whether or not you form incoming data (variable `linesProxy`):

1. If you do form incoming data: Always include all parts of the string. In your case, always ensure you have 4 (assuming `proxyAdrs[3]` is the last) parts by adding additional `:` between 1st and 3rd values if no value for 2nd is provided. Thus after `.Split()` operation (ensure you don't activate `RemoveEmptyStrings` option ) your `proxyAdrs[2]` will be `null` and your sample will be fine.
2. Otherwise: if `proxyAdrs[2]` is the only part the can be empty following snippet can prevent crashing:

   ```
   string[] proxyAdrs = linesProxy[i].Split(':');
   string proxyServer = proxyAdrs[0];
   int proxyPort = Convert.ToInt32(proxyAdrs[1]);    

   if(proxyAdrs.Length > 3)
   {
     if(proxyAdrs[2] != null)
         item.Username = proxyAdrs[2];
     if (proxyAdrs[3] != null)
         item.Password = proxyAdrs[3];
   }
   else
   {
    if(proxyAdrs[2] != null)
         item.Password = proxyAdrs[2];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    objCommonDD = new CommonDropDownBLL();
    objCommonDDEntity = new CommonDropdownEntity();

    //string strState=contextKey.ToString();
    string[] contextKeySplit = contextKey.Split('^');
    string strState = contextKeySplit[0].ToString();
    string strPin = contextKeySplit[1].ToString();

    objCommonDDEntity.TableName = "PCOM_PINCODES";
    objCommonDDEntity.DeleteField = "";
    objCommonDDEntity.TextField = "RTRIM(PIN_CITY_NAME) AS PC_DESC";
    objCommonDDEntity.ValueField = "DISTINCT PIN_CITY_CODE AS PC_CODE";

    objCommonDDEntity.StrCondition = " AND PIN_COUNTRY_CODE='IND' AND UPPER(PIN_CITY_NAME) LIKE UPPER('" + prefixText + "%') AND PIN_STATE_NAME='" + strState + "' AND PIN_CODE='" + strPin + "' ORDER BY PC_DESC";

    DataTable dtCity = new DataTable();
    dtCity = objCommonDD.GetData(objCommonDDEntity);

    string[] items = new string[dtCity.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dtCity.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        items.SetValue(dtCity.Rows[i]["PC_DESC"].ToString(), i);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO deepika!  It is not acceptable on SO use an answer to ask another question.  Please use the Ask Question button to ask a new question.  This has been flagged for deletion.